# Is it possible to set two absolute list lengths when validating a field?

Tags: python, pydantic

If I want to validate the length of a list I currently use:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, conlist
from typing import Annotated

class Match(BaseModel):
    player_ids: Annotated[List[int], conlist(int, min_length=2, max_length=4)]
```

But what if I want the list to either be 2 or 4 items in length?

Comment: What version of pydantic are you using?

Comment: Just write a [custom validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/)?